# The Witcher I - Awkward alchemy

Tags: the-witcher, the-witcher-series

I fully understand, that the game is pretty old. But it is still very nice and currently I do my first run in it.

I have also installed a [FCR](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher/mods/237/?) mod and started playing on the 4th level of difficulty (FCR gives an "easy" pack of three difficulties, and a "hard" pack with also three, so I'm in a hard). That's why I need to use alchemy a lot. That's why I have faced a problem that an alchemy interface is very inconvenient to use.

For example, I never know how many and which potions I can currently create. I need to find a fire or a bed, start meditation, go to alchemy mode, and only then I'll see a list of potions I can create (and still not the count of each kind of them).

Is there any way to fix this? I searched for mods on Nexus, and the only usefull thing for this I have found is [Better Color Coding](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher/mods/197/?) mod.

Maybe I do miss anything in a game? Or a carefull study of player's inventory is the only way for my issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's working as intended, the alchemy interface simply isn't that good. Several reasons for that: Many different ingredients do the same thing. Only the color matters (better color coding will help a lot highlighting this). Each ingredient contains one of the primaries and possibly one of the secondaries. So any ingredient with Quebrith is essentially the same as any other with Quebrith. Since the secondaries only work, when all ingredients contain it and because of the vast number of ingredients, the game simply doesn't support a lot of convenience features.

All you can do is click on the potion in your interface and the game will auto-fill in ingredients. If you can't brew it, you don't have enough.
But be careful here. The game likes to waste ingredients with secondaries this way.

Color-coding + sorting you alchemy bag will get you a good idea of what you have.

You can check all your potion formulae in the journal at any time.